# C++ Additive Blending Algorithm 2d Game

Tags: c++, alpha-blending

I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on whats going wrong with my additive blending here, I think I'm nearly there, currently my outcome is black squares. I have tried using both the formula's on this website here https://love2d.org/wiki/BlendMode_Formulas to try and get my desired outcome and it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the equation I have in my notes and what I have found online.
Final.Red = Bitmap.Red + Viewport.Red 
Similar for green and blue, RGB range is [0-1] or [0-255]

The colors I am using are 255 RGBA format.

```
void SpritePlotterForm::DrawSpriteAdd( int X, int Y, Bitmap^ SrcBitmap )
{

    int FinalViewPortRed;
    int FinalViewPortGreen;
    int FinalViewPortBlue;
    int FinalViewPortAlpha;
    for (int x = 0; x < SrcBitmap->Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SrcBitmap->Height; y++)
        {
          if (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A >= 0)
          {
                // resets to avoid corruptionj of image
                FinalViewPortRed = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).R + GetViewportPixel(x+ X, y + Y).R)/255;
                FinalViewPortGreen = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).G + GetViewportPixel(x + X, y + Y).G) / 255;
                FinalViewPortBlue = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).B + GetViewportPixel(x + X, y + Y).B) / 255;
                Color ResultColour = Color::FromArgb(FinalViewPortRed, FinalViewPortGreen, FinalViewPortBlue);
                SetViewportPixel(X + x, Y + y, ResultColour);

          }
       }
    }

}
```

I think the error is to do with how I am handling my alpha values, but I have tried multiple algorithms and either, end up darkening the image, creating a whole black square, or a whole transparent square, or worst is it gets an out of bounds issue.

Image to be blended
[image: The Image file to be additively blended]

the result  I get from this algorithm (run twice, those are two seperate flames there)

[image: The result]

Desired outcome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the final result as final.red = bitmap.red + viewport.red and divide by 255, then you are simply averaging them out, without taking alpha into account.
The way I learned to calculate transparency is a formula that is also present in the top of the page you linked:

> res.r = dst.r * (1 - src.a) + src.r * src.a
>      res.g = dst.g * (1 -src.a) + src.g * src.a
>      res.b = dst.b * (1 - src.a) + src.b * src.a

So that would be along the lines of

```
            // resets to avoid corruptionj of image
            FinalViewPortRed = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).R * SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A + GetViewportPixel(x+ X, y + Y).R) * (1-SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A);
            FinalViewPortGreen = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).G * SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A  + GetViewportPixel(x + X, y + Y).G)  * (1- SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A) ;
            FinalViewPortBlue = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).B  * SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A + GetViewportPixel(x + X, y + Y).B)  * (1-SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A) ;
```

It is then also important to adjust the new alpha value of the resulting color! (Since 2 transparent objects over each other will result in a color that is less transparent)!

> res.a = dst.a * (1 - src.a) + src.a

Again, this woud look probably someting ike this in your code:

```
            FinalViewPortAlpha = (SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A + GetViewportPixel(x + X, y + Y).A * (1-SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A) ;
```

**EDIT:**
Assuming you wanted or needed to use the formula you specified in your question, that seems to be a so called "premultiplied alpha" calculation. 
Your link has a brief description, but doesn't really say how alpha even comes into play.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) has a better description.
I think the most useful thing for you is the description (i manually put the **a** in, standing for alpha, the wiki has a concrete number, but we want to be more general)

> *If an alpha channel is used in an image, it is common to also multiply the color by the alpha value, to save on additional
>   multiplications during compositing. This is usually referred to as
>   premultiplied alpha.*

and also

> *...if this pixel uses premultiplied alpha, all of the RGB values (0, x, 0) are multiplied by **a** and then the alpha is appended to the
>   end to yield (0, x * **a** , 0, **a** ).*

I haven't used this formula, but it seems you simply multiply alpha ( => [0,1]) to all of it's colors (so src.r * src.a, scr.g * scr.a....) and then add up the colors in the end after doing so.

PS: Checking SrcBitmap->GetPixel(x, y).A >= 0 seems kind of pointless here, since alpha is [0,1], so that would need to always be true

Comment: sorry I've just tested this out and ive got an out of bounds error  where im returning -255 in one of the final alpha, can you help me out a bit again ? @Throzen

Comment: would using abs ? fix this ?

Comment: hmm, are you using [0, 255] for alpha ? I believe that alpha definitely needs to be between 0 and 1, otherwise the _"(1 - src.a)"_ wouldn't even make sense, since it's basically saying _"we want this much of a percentage of the source"_. So first make sure that alpha is definitely [0, 1].

Comment: No you are correct the alpha should be 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: Should but having said that peaking at the definition of the program, I think it may be 255, how do I adjust for that ?       -- The equation I had been given                                                                                             The additive blending equation is:
Final.Red = Bitmap.Red + Viewport.Red

Comment: comment became too long, added another possibility to why your formula might be _Final.Red = Bitmap.Red + Viewport.Red_  in my answer, just keep in mind I have never used this formula myself, so I cannot speak from experience, but the wiki is not bad describing premultiplied vs non-premultiplied´. And again, make sure to also adjust the resulting alpha value!

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far, I'll guess ill have to fiddle around with it, hopefully I'll find out by trail and error.